# Can I enable OK Google in my Nexus 5 even when phone is locked?

Tags: nexus-5, google-now, ok-google

I actually like OK Google, and would like to have it available even when the phone is locked / screen is off. Anyway to do that?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, your Nexus 5 will need the "always listening" mode.  It's not supported on this handset officially, but there are community developers working on enabling this feature.  As of this writing, the development is still in a (semi-)working [proof of concept](https://plus.google.com/+GuillaumeLesniak/posts/H4CiUhBRghi) stage.